# Which is correct: "participated in an" or "participated in the"?

Tags: articles, indian-english

This form:

> **Certificate**
>
> This is to certify that Mr/Ms. Ajay Meher has participated in an
> online webinar ‘Engineering Projects Management’ on  October 11, 2021.

Or this one:

> This is to certify that Mr/Ms. Ajay Meher has participated in the
> online webinar ‘Engineering Projects Management’ on  October 11, 2021.

Which is correct?

Comment: The certificate is being issued to someone specifically to record their participation in a particular course? If so, use "the", which always makes something sound more important and singular. If it's just a document, such as a CV, listing some courses they've taken, then you might say "they did a seminar XXX, another seminar YYY, etc".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer the second option,

> participated in **the** online webinar ‘Engineering Projects Management’

The first example isn't wrong, but it needs at least a comma after *webinar*. Better yet would be the word *named* instead of a comma,

> participated in **an** online webinar **named** ‘Engineering Projects Management’

In the second option, the name of the course is in apposition to "the online webinar". That fits because they are both specific expressions.

I don't think "**an** online webinar" makes a good appositive for the exact
course name, so the descriptive phrase "named..." fits better.

On the other hand, if the order of the phrases is changed,

> participated in ‘Engineering Projects Management’, **an** online webinar

then **an** fits, because you've used the more specific phrase first, and added a descriptive phrase after it.